# data from a row to a column in python pandas

Tags: transformation

In a dataframe:

```
DATA1   DATA2   DATA3   DATA4   DATA5   DATA6   DATA7
-----------------------------------------------------------------
12      13      14      15      16      17      11
```

how do I transpose the data to the followings?

In rows

```
-------------
12
13
14
15
16
17
11
```

Answer (score 0):

`df.T` will transpose your `DataFrame`

```
In [9]: import pandas as pd

In [10]: df = pd.DataFrame([{'data1': 12, 'data2': 13, 'data3': 14}])

In [11]: df
Out[11]: 
   data1  data2  data3
0     12     13     14

In [12]: df.T
Out[12]: 
        0
data1  12
data2  13
data3  14

In [13]:
```